# How to execute jar file from JMeter in Linux / CentOS

Tags: linux, jar, centos, jmeter

I have a jar file which i can execute from JMeter Bean Shell Sampler like below.

```
cmd /c java -jar myjar.jar param1
```

How can i execute the same jar file from JMeter in Linux/CentOS?

Comment: You can usually run a jar file with $ `java -jar myjar.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Just [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String-) method like

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command here");
```

Also be aware that JMeter provides [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) so you should be able to execute commands and programs without having to do Beanshell scripting. See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for detailed explanation and walkthrough.

Few recommendations for any approach:

- On Windows use forward slashes in file paths like:

  ```
  c:/folder/otherfolder/file
  ```
- Use full paths to any programs just in case

  ```
  c:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c c:/java/bin/java.exe -jar d:/myJar/my.jar -param
  ```

Comment: Im using Linux. What is the full path i should use in Linux?